# Bind js event to document except 1 element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a popup and want to hide it when it is clicked anywhere outside, but one element (which is another popup, let say div#AnotherPopup). Then I click on #AnotherPopup, it should not hide the original one.. It does now, because I have this:

```
  $(document).bind('click', methods.hide);
```

How to bind it to document, except #AnotherPopup ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really but you can check inside `methods.hide` if the target element is `#AnotherPopup` and immediately return out of the function before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The click handler for #AnotherPopup is to stop document from getting a click event.

```
$(document).bind("click", function () {
   alert(this.innerHTML) 
});
$('#AnotherPopup').click(function () {return false;});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtvLY/1)

Comment: So.. You're actually binding eventhandlers to all DOM elements except one? That's not a good idea.

Comment: @erlando, that's what the OP asked for

Comment: But it's not the right way to do it at all. In this case it would be far far better to bind to document and then check for #AnotherPopup. To bind to /every/ element in the DOM is unnecessary and resource-heavy.

Comment: @erlando, what do you think about it now?

Answer (score -1):

By using unbind you can do this:

```
$(document).bind('click',methods.hide);
$('#AnotherPopup').unbind('click',methods.hide);
```

Read more about [unbind here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: I don't think that would work. methods.hide is not actually bound to #AnotherPopup, it's bound to document. Therefore there's nothing to unbind...