# Attach event to document other than 1 div

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onclicklistener

I have created an inspector type feature that will give you a divs ID when you click anything on the page. I have used:

```
document.attachEvent('click', inspectorOnClick);
```

I've now decided to add another feature, I now need this event attached to everything in the document other than one div is that possible?

EDIT:
I thought one of the links in the comments solved my problem, but there is a bit more to it than I thought.

Let me explain, when the document loads.

```
    document.attachEvent('click', inspectorOnClick);
```

Is attached, once an element is clicked I dynamically create an overlay div in the position of the cursor. I want to take the event off of this dynamically created div. I have tried:

```
//prepend dynamicly created div to body 
document.body.insertBefore(overlayDiv, document.body.childNodes[0];
var getOverlay = document.getElementsByClassName('bsOverlay');
getOverlay.attachEvent("click", function(){ return false; }
```

I have also tried a different last line which is

```
getOverlay.detachEvent("click", inspectorCancel)
```

Comment: How do you want to control what element to ignore? Are you using IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind js event to document except 1 element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667056/bind-js-event-to-document-except-1-element)

Comment: you need to stop bubbling to parent element for the respective element

Comment: Preferably by ID and no i'm not but IE compatibility wouldn't hurt. also I cannot use Jquery

Comment: Thanks for the link MelanciaUK. i did search for a question like this but guess my search terms suck. thanks for the link.

Comment: @NisseEngström the accepted answer in the duplicate doesn't imply the use of jQuery and is better than assigning a new event to any elements except one.